# What handshakes happen (or need to happen) when I connect my FPGA with Ethernet cable to my home router+modem device in one of its ethernet port?

Tags: networking, router, ip, ethernet, tcp

I have a FPGA edge device. I want to send and receive ethernet packets to my laptop through the router+modem device at my house. My laptop is connected to the router+modem through the wifi (for internet) and I am connecting my FPGA board to the router+modem through a ethernet cable.

1. What protocols and handshakes should I implement in my FPGA so that when I send an ethernet packet with the destination IP+MAC address of my laptop to the router+modem device, it forwards that ethernet packet to my laptop connected to it through the wifi?
2. And same way when my laptop sends an ethernet packet with destination IP+MAC address of my FPGA to the router, it forwards it to my FPGA connected to it through the ethernet cable?
3. How exactly will the router know what is the IP+MAC address of my FPGA (which handshake will save that info into the router)?
4. If the FPGA can do TCP 3way handshake, respond to ARP requests and ping requests, will that be enough to perform the required task I have stated at the top? How will these handshakes make that possible, what happens exactly when the ethernet cable is plugged into the router and what handshakes does the router need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a home/personal use device that is marketed as a "router" which actually includes a layer-2 switch for the LAN, and a layer-3 router (perhaps with NAT) to internetwork the LAN to the WAN.

> What protocols and handshakes should I implement in my FPGA so that when I send an ethernet packet with the destination IP+MAC address of my laptop to the router+modem device, it forwards that ethernet packet to my laptop connected to it through the wifi?

If you have a static IP address for the FPGA, you simply need to establish and train the Ethernet link, and then you'll be good to go to send data with fixed source and destination IP and MAC addresses. If you want a dynamic IP for the FPGA, you need to support DHCP (and everything else it relies on such as UDP)

> And same way when my laptop sends an ethernet packet with destination IP+MAC address of my FPGA to the router, it forwards it to my FPGA connected to it through the ethernet cable?

If the FPGA has a static IP, you just need ARP to allow the laptop to discover the correct layer-2 address to use in the link-layer header of the frame. There's no need to take any special action to make the switch aware of which port the FPGA is on. It will [just work](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29321/how-does-a-switch-learn-a-mac-address-not-in-its-lookup-table) by flooding the packet to all switch ports at first, and then discovering the correct port to use as soon as the FPGA transmits its first frame of *any* kind with the correct source MAC set.

> How exactly will the router know what is the IP+MAC address of my FPGA (which handshake will save that info into the router)?

The router doesn't necessarily need to know this to properly handle data traveling to and from the FPGA. It might list (on its status page) it as an unknown device, or not list it whatsoever.

> If the FPGA can do TCP 3way handshake, respond to ARP requests and ping requests, will that be enough to perform the required task I have stated at the top? How will these handshakes make that possible, what happens exactly when the ethernet cable is plugged into the router and what handshakes does the router need?

See above. Ethernet link training establishes layer 1 (physical). At layer 2 (link-layer) the switch will discover MAC address -> port mappings during communication and flood packets to all ports (non-destination devices will ignore those packets) if it needs to send a frame before the correct port is known. Layer 3 IP addresses resolve to MAC addresses because of ARP, and the IP addresses themselves can be either configured statically or over DHCP.

Comment: thanks, (1) so basically in case of static IP address for my FPGA, my FPGA should only be able to respond to ARP requests, then the router will know about the FPGA and its IP address? 
2) Does the TCP 3way handshake need to happen between my FPGA and router as soon as I connect to it?
3) Do I need to go to router settings and input my FPGAs MAC and IP as a static IP in the router settings or will the router discover it on itsown as you stated?

Comment: @AZ123 The *router* portion of your box (which is confusingly called a router) doesn't need to know or care. The ARP response is for the benefit of your laptop, so it knows what destination MAC to use. WIth the destination MAC properly set, the switch will deliver the packet to the correct port (or all ports if it doesn't know which). The router/switch do not care one bit about the TCP connection. They only deal with link-layer frames and IP packets. The three-way-handshake is between the laptop and the FPGA.

Comment: (1) So in this case the router/switch/modem/box will send the incoming packet from my laptop to all its ports (you mean ethernet ports here or all the devices connected to it either through wifi of ethernet?) 
(2) I sent a valid ethernet frame from my FPGA to the router with destination MAC of my laptop with a dummy payload (No TCP IP inside the frame), but my laptop did not receive it through the wifi. Whereas my laptop did receive it when I sent the same ethernet frame from my FPGA directly connected to laptop through the laptop's ethernet port (saw it in wireshark on laptop).

Comment: @AZ123 Flooding applies to Ethernet ports. The WiFi phy and link layer already know the connected MAC addresses and transmit a frame from the antenna which can very well reach all devices. In your case, your box may try to actually route (at layer 3) data moving between Ethernet and WiFi devices, in which case you may want to transmit a frame with a valid IP header (but not necessarily TCP)

Comment: Oh that makes it extremely clear. Thanks a lot!!!